# If condition not working if (str == "1") while data is returning 1

Tags: javascript

If condition not working while data is returning 1 and 0 but it always execute the else code, i am unable to find error, code is working fine on localhot but not on server

```
$('#by_head_name').on('blur', function() {

    var headsubt = document.getElementById('by_head_name').value;

    if (headsubt !== "") {

        //alert('hi');  

        $.post('verify-head-or-subhead-name.php', {
                headsub: headsubt

            },
            function(data, status) {

                var str = data;

                if (str == "1") {

                    var headd = "ok";

                    alert('ok');

                } else if (str == "0") {

                    alert("No Head Exist, Please choose valid Head or create one before selecting it");

                } else {
                    alert(data);
                    this.value == '';
                }


            });



    }
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate: But then that would evaluate to true

Comment: Try replacing `if (str == "1") {` with `if (str) {`.

Comment: Have you tried to step through it with a debugger? Also, make sure you have no whitespace in your result.

Comment: What is the value of `str`. Do `console.log(str);` before the if statement and show us the console output. `data` is obviously not what you think it is

Comment: Clearly `str` is neither `"1"` nor `"0"` ?

Comment: @Carcigenicate - as it's doing non-strict comparison, string or number doesn't matter.

Comment: Try to run case tests on chrome devtool ,take pices of your code and just run them with hard values. you will learn a lot from that . also use chrome devtool/snippet that you can find in `devtool/Source/left menu/snippets` for more easy play with long test

Comment: I'll bet there's whitespace around the number, try using `var str = data.trim();`

Comment: @Barmar Thank you Sir, var str = data.trim(); solved my problem, now my code is working on server too. i am not getting the point that why it was working on localhost earlier.

Comment: I want to thank all programmers who replied to my question, it was my first question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check what "data" of the success function returns in your alert message.

If it returns string directly, then your condition should work.

If it shows object in the alert screen, please verify your object and accordingly choose a variable which satisfy your condition like data.value.

Comment: "data" of the success function returns string 1 or string 0

Comment: What you r getting in alert box ?, you said else is executing always.

Comment: i am getting 0 or 1 in alert box, i think there was a white space in the code now i used " str = data.trim(); " and code is working fine on my server

Comment: Thanks You Sir for your suggestions